# absolute values in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function that returns the absolute value of an integer...

```
abs :: Int -> Int

abs n | n >= 0    = n
      | otherwise = -n


myabs :: Int -> Int

myabs n = if n >= 0 then n else -n
```

They both work for positive integers but not negative integers.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 13):

Both of them seem to work just fine:

```
Main> myabs 1
1
Main> myabs (-1)
1
Main> abs 1
1
Main> abs (-1)
1
```

Answer (score 10):

Ahh! I didn't know you had to include brackets in...

```
myabs (-1)
```

someone pass the dunces cap.
dohhh

Comment: This should be a comment (you can do that now). :)

Answer (score 6):

Right, you usually need to parenthesise negative values to disambiguate operator precedence. For more details, see [Real World Haskell chapter 1](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/getting-started.html#starting.calc.neg).